# How to create database first approach exact class project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, design-patterns

I just doing a simple CRUD operation using database first approach. I have an ASP.NET MVC project and another a class library project.

I already mentioned `ManageEmployee.Management` is a class library project, and `ManageEmployee.Web` is the ASP.NET MVC web project.

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=MCH-DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS; Database=AutoSoftSystems; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" 
                   -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
                   -OutputDir "Models" 
                   -ContextDir "Data" -Context "EmployeeDbContext"
```

Running this command on the Package Manager console works fine, but the file is generated in the web project.

I want to change path direction. How can I change my path to the `ManageEmployee.Management` folder?

Answer (score 2):

Your Default project in Package Manager console is `ManageEmployee.Web`, you should change that to `ManageEmployee.Management` and your `EmoloyeeDBContext` need to be in `ManageEmployee.Management` also - then you run command to generate models.

Btw I'm pretty sure that if you say that your `-OutputDir "../ManageEmployee.Management/Models"` that should work also. I have never tried this last part but I think that is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I am highly recommended to use [EfCorePowertool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) visual studio plugin. It is more helpful for me to reverse engineer my existing database through a GUI.

Using that tool you can put the path `../ManageEmployee.Management/Models` like the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: screenshot are hidden, But thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can solved my problem, I just change defaut Project name

[image]